# How C# Automapper can set the fields to null when the string is empty

Tags: c#, automapper

Is there a way to set all properties of a class, that I'm mapping, that is `string.Empty` should map to `NULL`.

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDest>();
```

I want that all Properties of `TSource` that are string Empty are mapped to `NULL` in `TDest` corresponding Properties.

I've currently not found a way to globally assign this condition without setting it up for all Properties manually.

**EDIT**

I need it only for a specific mapping not for all maps defined in my application.

Answer (score 5):

```
cfg.CreateMap<string, string>().ConvertUsing(s=>s == "" ? (string)null : s);
```

Comment: Ok it works. But I need to use this convert only for a specific map, not for all mapping I defined in my application.

Comment: Try [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-transformers.html).

Comment: I need a newer version to use that. But at the moment I  can't update the version of Automapper

Comment: Then you need to apply a resolver with conditions. Search keywords: ForAllPropertyMaps or ForAllMaps and ForAllMembers.

Comment: Can you provide an example please or where I can find it?

Comment: You can check the tests in the repo or simply google it.