# How to handle multiple null filed by auto mapper base on their type default value

Tags: c#, null, automapper

There are personnel and personnelDto classes which are serialized by auto mapper. There are almost 30 string and int null allowed fields, is there any way to map all null strings to "" and null int values to 0, I already done it manually.

```
CreateMap<Personnel, PersonnelDto>()
 .ForMember(a => a.PersonnelName, o => o.MapFrom(a => 
                  a.PersonnelName == null ? "" : a.PersonnelName))
 .ForMember(a => a.PersonnelOccupationId, o => o.MapFrom(a => 
                  a.PersonnelOccupationId == null ? 0 : 
                  a.PersonnelOccupationId))
 .ForMember(a => a.PersonnelGroupId, o => o.MapFrom(a => a.PersonnelGroupId == null ? 0 : a.PersonnelGroupId))
 .ForMember(a => a.CompanyId, o => o.MapFrom(a => a.CompanyId == null ? 0 : a.CompanyId))
  .ForMember(a => a.PersonnelTitleId, o => o.MapFrom(a => a.PersonnelTitleId == null ? 0 : a.PersonnelTitleId));
``
```

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html). The null checks are built in. You can simply remove them. About strings, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53450418/how-c-sharp-automapper-can-set-the-fields-to-null-when-the-string-is-empty/53450689#53450689.

Comment: I t can be done one by one, I need to change all null values to empty string in one line globally.

Comment: That does the _exact_ reverse.